# How to disprove that there is an inner product on $\mathbb{R^2}$ s.t. the norm is $||(x_1,x_2)|| = |x_1|+|x_2|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I disprove that there is an inner product on $\mathbb{R^2}$ s.t. the norm is $||(x_1,x_2)|| = |x_1|+|x_2|$?

My approach is to use the parallelogram law to show that if I have two vectors $u,w \in \mathbb{R^2}$, then if it ISNT a norm,

$||u+w||^2+||u-w||^2 \neq 2(||u||^2+||w||^2)$.

However, I dont understand why this parallelogram law would show anything as the theorem in my book didnt mentioned anything about the parallelogram law and norms. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the norm is induced by an inner product, parallelogram law necessarily holds, since

$$
\left\|u+w\right\|^2+\left\|u-w\right\|^2=\left<u+w, u+w\right> + \left<u-w, u-w\right>=\\
= \left<u, u\right> + 2\left<u, w\right>+\left<w, w\right> + \left<u, u\right> - 2\left<u, w\right>+\left<w, w\right> =\\
\\
=2\left(\left<u, u\right>+\left<w, w\right>\right)=2\left(\left\|u\right\|^2+\left\|w\right\|^2\right)
$$

As it does not hold for the norm in question, it cannot be induced by an inner product.

Example: $u=(1,1)$, $w=(0,3)$.

Comment: So am I right to say that if the inner product doesn't hold, then somewhere along the lines of the construction you did, the norm of the two vectors don't yield the right answer? Do you know where exactly in the multiple equations you wrote would it go wrong? Thank you sir!

Comment: Implication goes like this: if it's induced by the inner product, parallelogram law holds for all $u$, $w$. So yes, if we can find two vectors such that this equality is not satisfied, we're done. Edit: wrong example, give me a moment

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example